# Asp net web.config httpErrors clear all status code except 400

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have Asp .net project and i handle errors like this:

```
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <clear />
      <error statusCode="500" path="503.html" responseMode="File" />
    </httpErrors>
```

i want that bad request error 400 not be replaced, so i can get the message from the front end, there is any solution for that

Comment: First check the source of 400 errors using failed request tracing. If they come from http.sys then you cannot customise them in any way https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/error#how-to

Comment: I cannot understand waht you want to. IIS does not define error pages for 400 errors, so the 400 error you see in the browser already contains the error message. It's error page never be replaced. If you want to troubleshoot 400 error, you can enable fail request tracing or check the IIS log.